# Graph structure for data wiki

Tags: graph, neo4j

I want to build a graph for data wiki. Every node can be changed by a user, but there will be an archive of all the changes made by users to the node's properties and relationships.

- Should I use a RDBMS instead of a graph?
- What structure should I use for the graph?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very vague question. What are your thoughts regarding each of those questions? Which way are you leaning as far as RDBMS VS Graph? How were you planning on structuring the graph?

Comment: @subvertallchris Well, I prefer a Graph because I intend to use the same graph for another related project. About the structure I thought maybe to make a node for each change that is made and from it specify what properties/relationships were changed - but i'm not sure about that.